# How to get a touch event outside the view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

We can tap a NavigationItem in a rect that larger than the item rect displayed.
I know `UINavigationItem` is not a subclass of `UIView`, but the Accessibility Inspector tell me its trait is Button. I'm confused.
When we touch inside a button but not lift, then move the finger outside the button, the button is still in touch, how does that works?
I want to know how dose the responder chain works in this case.
1. How does the button become the first responder when we touch inside it.
2. How could the button know whether I lift my finger outside it.
3. What does the responder chain look like throughout this?
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cuestom `UINavigationItem` with `initWithCustomView:` and pass in a custom `UIView` of which `hitTest:withEvent:` is overridden to return self with bigger touch area.

Comment: Thank you. UINavigationItem is more complex than I could think. But the selector hitTest:withEvent: is what I'm looking for. I think pointInside:withEvent: is the method we should modify to let my custom views or controls have a larger respond area.

Answer (score 0):

when you touch the button or sth else, it becomes the responder. And it will be the only responder of your this touch event until your finger leaves the screen, no matter where your finger is. 
you will get the detail info here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH1-SW1

Comment: I see. Until the touchesEnd:withEvent: happens, the button is always the first responder, and touchesMoved:withEvent: is sent to the button first.